# PHP code for getting data from a db then display in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Am new to sql, mysql and php. However, am learning. I have a database that collects students admission records. I want a PHP script to extract some fields from the students profile and print in a table.

Below ia sample of the database structure and an entry.

```
Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `salt` text,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` text,
  `password` text,
  `email` text,
  `register_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_salt` text,
  `level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` text,
  `profile` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9653 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`salt`, `userid`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `register_date`, `active`, `reg_salt`, `level`, `ip`, `profile`)

Within the 'Profile' column are data subsets that the user or admin enters via the website in a XML defined table. An example below

VALUES
('fc61f', 1, 'Admin', 'mutolo', 'smutolo@gmail.com', 1200247562, 1, 'e14973fc61f2bf249c540eb14b8525', 1, 'a:7:{s:14:"82.145.221.205";i:1;s:13:"82.145.221.54";i:1;s:14:"105.166.190.60";i:1;s:15:"197.181.203.204";i:1;s:14:"197.178.16.134";i:11;s:14:"105.166.241.43";i:1;s:15:"197.178.252.241";i:1;}', 'a:21:{s:10:"first_name";s:5:"Nzisa";s:9:"last_name";s:4:"Muli";s:6:"Gender";s:4:"Male";s:6:"County";s:0:"";s:8:"District";s:0:"";s:8:"Location";s:0:"";s:5:"Chief";s:0:"";s:6:"Orphan";s:25:"Yes Both Parents Deceased";s:6:"Parent";s:0:"";s:9:"Emergency";s:0:"";s:7:"Primary";s:0:"";s:4:"KCPE";s:0:"";s:20:"A_Little_Information";s:29:"I am the school administrator";s:9:"Notify_Me";s:1:"1";s:11:"alumni_year";s:4:"2010";s:7:"Picture";N;s:17:"alumni_include_me";s:1:"1";s:6:"Stream";s:0:"";s:9:"Admission";s:0:"";s:5:"House";s:0:"";s:8:"user_pic";s:5:"1.JPG";}'),
('4a1b6', 9641, 'bb', 'c80d5f83dbf874c4caebedfde385e1af', 'smutolo@gmail.com', 1389444756, 0, 'a2becf9eff6dbcde14ef8c1274a1b6', 10, NULL, 'a:21:
<====profile data starts here====>
    {s:10:"first_name";s:6:"Stella";s:9:"last_name";s:4:"King";s:6:"Gender";s:6:"Female";s:6:"County";s:5:"Kitui";s:8:"District";s:8:"Katulani";s:8:"Location";s:8:"Kathungi";s:5:"Chief";s:13:"Mr. Kasasaana";s:6:"Orphan";s:19:"Yes Father Deceased";s:6:"Parent";s:17:"Mr. Mutua Stephen";s:9:"Emergency";s:27:"Mr. Mutua Stephen-074321234";s:7:"Primary";s:7:"Kakuswi";s:4:"KCPE";s:3:"234";s:20:"A_Little_Information";s:39:"Am good in soccer\r\n\r\nAm allergic to oil";s:9:"Notify_Me";s:1:"1";s:11:"alumni_year";s:4:"2010";s:7:"Picture";N;s:17:"alumni_include_me";s:1:"1";s:6:"Stream";s:7:"1 South";s:9:"Admission";s:4:"3423";s:5:"House";s:5:"Nyayo";s:8:"user_pic";s:8:"9641.JPG";}')
```

I want a SQL and PHP code to extract some or all of the data in the column Profile.

Hope am clear. Thanks alot

Comment: Excellent job dumping the data. But you haven't told us what effort you have made.

Comment: Go through some tutorials, search on Google

Comment: Whoever designed that table probably didn't know what Normalisation is. All that data in the `ip` and `profile` fields should really be in separate tables. It would make life so much easier should you need to query or update any of it. If using PHP you'll want to use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to read the data from the database, and by the looks of it the PHP [Unserialise](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to decode it.

Comment: http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson20.php. Is outdated. with mysql functions, but its a good start

Answer (score 0):

To select all the results from DB you can do

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
```

This will fetch everything (All Users and ALL Columns).

To fetch a specific user you can do

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userid` = 1
```

the above query will fetch a user with user id 1

Both of the above queries will fetch all the columns. In order to get a specific column you can do

```
 SELECT `username` FROM `users`
```

it will give you all user names

Or for a specific user, you can again use the Where clause...So it will be

```
 SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `userid` = 1
```

Comment: I can use sql to query any column in the table, so thats no problem so far. My issue is, within the 'Profile' COLUMN, there are different types of data-First name, Last Name, Gender, County, District etc. How do I get the data from the profile column in a table? For instance, I want to extract First names, Last names and gender from the profile data.

The portal is here http://www.onlinestudentsadmission.com/schooldemo

Thanks

Comment: U should make a separate table for profiles instead of just putting all profile data into one big text datatype.

Comment: Thanks B_Cooper. I know that would be easier. However, this is a script that was meant for an Alumni website and am customising it for admitting students online. The authors idea was for the buyer to be able to add custom fields in the profile page via xml. Although it serves my purpose right as it is, am thinking of adding more functionality and therefore value to users. for instance, one may need to get a print out of all male students who were admitted in a certain year. Or a combination, like, all female students from a certain county admitted in a certain year. 

Thanks.

Comment: ok so in the profile column as you mentioned that there are different types of data, but do you know its sequence? like first thing in it will always be first_name, then second one will be last name and so on...if the sequence is confirmed then that can be done too... let me know

Comment: Omicans, yes, there is a sequence. below is a portion of the profile data that was in put by a user on the website.

Comment: Once a user registers on the website, a profile page is generated like this http://www.onlinestudentsadmission.com/schooldemo/show_alumni.php?id=9652.

The values for the profile fields are pulled from the 'profile column' in the db. They follow the sequence as defined in the profile page.

Hope am clear.

Comment: Below is a portion of data in the profile  column. The same sequence is followed for every user.
{s:10:"first_name";s:6:"Stella";s:9:"last_name";s:4:"King";s:6:"Gender";s:6:"Female";s:6:"County";s:5:"Kitui";s:8:"District";s:8:"Katulani";s:8:"Location";s:8:"Kathungi";s:5:"Chief";s:13:"Mr. Kasasaana";s:6:"Orphan";s:19:"Yes Father Deceased";s:6:"Parent";s:17:"Mr. Mutua Stephen";s:9:"Emergency";s:27:"Mr. Mutua Stephen-074321234";s:7:"Primary";...............continues to last profile field.